# Constructor visibility restricted to file

Tags: kotlin, android-sharedpreferences

I want to create an easier way to handle SharedPreferences.
The way I want to call it is like this

get preference:

```
val email = SharedPrefs.userdata.email
val wifiOnly = SharedPrefs.connections.wifiOnly
```

set preference:

```
SharedPrefs.userdata.email = "someone@example.com"
SharedPrefs.connections.wifiOnly = true
```

I'm able to do so like this:

`App.instance` returns a `Context` object in the following snippet

```
object SharedPrefs {

    val userdata by lazy { UserPreferences() }
    val connections by lazy { ConnectionPreferences() }

    class UserPreferences {

        private val prefs: SharedPreferences = App.instance.getSharedPreferences("userdata", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

        var email: String
            get() = prefs.getString("email", null)
            set(value) = prefs.edit().putString("email", value).apply()
    }

    class ConnectionPreferences {

        private val prefs: SharedPreferences = App.instance.getSharedPreferences("connections", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

        var wifyOnly: Boolean
            get() = prefs.getBoolean("wifiOnly", false)
            set(value) = prefs.edit().putBoolean("wifyOnly", value).apply()
    }

}
```

The problem is that this can still be called: `SharedPrefs.UserPreferences()`
Can I make this constructor private to this file or object only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can separate the interface and the implementation class, and make the latter `private` to the object:

```
object SharedPrefs {
    val userdata: UserPreferences by lazy { UserPreferencesImpl() }

    interface UserPreferences {
        var email: String
    }

    private class UserPreferencesImpl : UserPreferences {
        private val prefs: SharedPreferences = 
            App.instance.getSharedPreferences("userdata", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

        override var email: String
            get() = prefs.getString("email", null)
            set(value) = prefs.edit().putString("email", value).apply()
    }


    // ...
}
```

Alternatively, if you are developing a library or you have a modular architecture, you can make use of the [`internal` visibility](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/visibility-modifiers.html#modules) modifier to restrict the visibility to the module:

```
class UserPreferences internal constructor() { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: This works just like I need it. Too bad it requires more coding

Answer (score -1):

You can try something like this

```
class UserPreferences private constructor()
{
    // your impl
}
```

[This](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/visibility-modifiers.html#constructors) is the reference

Comment: This makes it unreachable for the upper object SharedPrefs. Cannot access '<init>': it is private in UserPreferences

Comment: replacing the `private` with `internal` makes it only visible within the same module. But this does also not fit perfectly to your needs.